# Registration of My Domain is pending

Tags: mydomain

I have setup a My domain on my CS3 sandbox about 6 hours ago. Normally it takes about few minutes. I think there i an issue here.

**Your domain name registration is pending**

Has anyone know why it is not completed.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

As per Documentation from Salesforce its mentioning as  " It may take up to 48 hours for your registration to take effect."
Click [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sites_creating_subdomain.htm&language=en_US)

Comment: Also checked the http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/instances for CS3 for any issue in box and coudn't find any issue in past & today till now. Might need to wait for some more time as mentioned by Saleforce.